# Laravel Pagination 3 dots not showing

Tags: laravel

I ran the command to generate the customization files for my blog's pagination.

I was able to customize the appearance of the buttons but the issue I now have is that when the page number gets to say 8, the pagination link shows up to 8 links. I would like to implement the '...' separator within the link. My bootstrap-4.blade.php is as follows

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">

      <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
            {{-- Previous Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->onFirstPage())
            <li>
                <a  aria-label="Next">
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            @else
                <li class="px-1">
                    <a  href="{{ $paginator->previousPageUrl() }}" rel="prev" aria-label="@lang('pagination.previous')">  <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></span></a>
                </li>
            @endif

            {{-- Pagination Elements --}}
            @foreach ($elements as $element)
                {{-- "Three Dots" Separator --}}
                @if ($paginator->currentPage() > 4 && $page === 2)
                <li class="px-1"><span class="page-link">...</span></li>
                @endif



                {{-- Array Of Links --}}
                @if (is_array($element))
                    @foreach ($element as $page => $url)
                        @if ($page == $paginator->currentPage())
                              <li class="px-1"><a style="background:#56107c; color:white; cursor:not-allowed;" href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                        @else
                            <li class="px-1"><a href="{{ $url }}">{{ $page }}</a></li>
                        @endif
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach

            {{-- Next Page Link --}}
            @if ($paginator->hasMorePages())
                <li class="px-1">
                  <a  href="{{ $paginator->nextPageUrl() }}" rel="next" aria-label="@lang('pagination.next')">  <span><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></span></a>
                </li>
            @else
            <li>
                <a  aria-label="Next">
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i>
                </a>
            </li>
            @endif
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use a built in function `$posts->links()`, it will auto create everything - links, numbers and next.

Comment: Yes, I am already doing this, my issue is it's not generating the '...''s inbetween the links....

Comment: but $post->links() don't show dots it will only show page number like page 1 of 10.

Comment: thanks for that tip, which command shows the dots?